# Apple Mach-O Linker Error for "_AudioServicesCreateSystemSound" and 1 other

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, frameworks

I'm relatively new to iOS development and I've come across this error. I was just adding a sound to my project and I've already imported the AudioToolbox.Framework but when I try to build the project it gives me the above error.It also gives me "Apple Mach-O Linker Error _AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID" and "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation".

This is my code:

CurrentLocationViewController.m

```
@implementation CurrentLocationViewController {
        CLLocationManager *locationManager;
        CLLocation *location;
        BOOL updatingLocation;
        NSError *lastLocationError;
        CLGeocoder *geocoder;
        CLPlacemark *placemark;
        BOOL performingReverseGeocoding;
        NSError *lastGeocodingError;
        UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
        SystemSoundID soundID;
    }
```

And:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self updateLabels];
    [self configureGetButton];
    [self loadSoundEffect];
}
```

Also:

```
        lastGeocodingError = error;
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            if (placemark == nil) {
                NSLog(@"First Time!");
                [self playSoundEffect];
            }
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
        } else {
            placemark = nil;
        }
```

And finally:

```
#pragma mark - Sound Effect

- (void)loadSoundEffect
{
    NSString *path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound.caf" ofType:nil];

    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
    if (fileURL == nil) {
        NSLog(@"NSURL is nil for file file path: %@", path);
        return;
    }

    OSStatus error = AudioServicesCreateSystemSound((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL,&soundID);

    if (error != kAudioServicesNoError) {
        NSLog(@"Error code %ld loading sound at path: %@", error, path);
        return;
    }
}

- (void)unloadSoundEffect
{
    AudioSystemDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
    soundID = 0;
}

- (void)playSoundEffect
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

@end
```

On the lines when I call AudioSystem/Services there is a yellow warning saying "Implicit declaration of function '(What was on that line)' is invalid in C99"

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: linker error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `AudioServicesCreateSystemSound` to `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID`